# WPF - Drawing a line of text with different background colors

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5, wpf-controls

I need to draw a line of text with that has a different background for part of the string (i.e. like a highlight) in WPF.  The FomattedText class allows you to set various attributes for different parts of a string like bold, underline fore color etc but does not have background color. I think using TextFormatter and writing a custom TextSource will do the job but it seems like a fairly heavy weight way of doing something quite simple. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a basic TextBlock with multiple Inline children and giving them separate background colors.  Here is a simple example in XAML:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Background="Blue">Foo</Run>
    <Run Background="Red">Bar</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Note that a ContentPresenter with no template will automatically wrap Inline objects in a TextBlock, so you can just bind the Content property of a ContentControl to a Span.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines) for advice on data binding to Inlines.

If you want the text to be editable by the user, then you should look at [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx).