# Using ValueConverter with Inlines

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to use ValueConverter with Inlines? I need some parts of the every line in a ListBox bolded.

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Inlines>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource InlinesConverter}">
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="FName"/>
     </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Inlines>  
</TextBlock>
```

It compiles but I get:
A 'MultiBinding' cannot be used within a 'InlineCollection' collection. A 'MultiBinding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

If that is not possible, what approach would you suggest to be able to pass the whole TextBlock to IValueConverter?

Comment: You don't need a MultiBinding when there's only one value to bind. Try Binding instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone else pointed out, `Inlines` is not a `Dependency Property` which is why you are getting that error. When I've run across similar situations in the past, I've found `Attached Properties`/`Behaviors` to be a good solution. I'm going to assume that `FName` is of type `string`, and consequently so is the attached property. Here's an example:

```
class InlinesBehaviors
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoldInlinesProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BoldInlines", typeof(string), typeof(InlinesBehaviors), 
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnBoldInlinesChanged));

    private static void OnBoldInlinesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = d as TextBlock;
        if (textBlock != null) 
        {
            string fName = (string) e.NewValue; // value of FName
            // You can modify Inlines in here
            ..........
        }
    }

    public static void SetBoldInlines(TextBlock element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BoldInlinesProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetBoldInlines(TextBlock element)
    {
        return (string) element.GetValue(BoldInlinesProperty);
    }
}
```

You could then use this in the following way (`my` is the xml namespace pointing to the namespace containing the `AttachedProperty`):

```
<TextBlock my:InlinesBehaviors.BoldInlines="{Binding FName}" />
```

The binding above could have been a multi binding, you could have used a converter, or whatever. `Attached Behaviors` are pretty powerful and this seems like a good place to use them.

Also, in case you're interested, here's an [article](http://eladm.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/attached-behavior/) on `Attached Behaviors`.

Comment: I have several errors on "public static readonly DependencyProperty BoldInlinesProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BoldInlines", typeof(string), typeof("InlinesBehaviors"), 
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnBoldInlinesChanged));"

Comment: I got it, "InlinesBehaviors" should be without quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have seen many posts mentioning it is not possible and not event a quick&dirty solutions were suggested. I knew someone must know the solution.

Comment: I only just saw your comments, I'm glad you were able to figure out my typo and that I could help.

Answer (score 4):

I ran across this question while searching for a solution to the same error of "A 'MultiBinding' cannot be used within a 'InlineCollection' collection".  My problem was not with the `InLines` property, but I had inadvertently left out the `<TextBlock.Text>` tag when defining my `MultiBinding` for my `TextBlock`.  Just something to check if you're also getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Inlines` is not a `DependencyProperty` - that's basically what the error message is saying.

[See here for possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines).

Comment: That makes sense. This is also beginner's question, but is there a way to bold numbers in a TextBlock's Text with datatriggers?