# Wrap text nicely in horizontal stackpanel or wrappanel?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, stackpanel, word-wrap, wrappanel

I've seen a few other posts about this but haven't seen anything that solves my problem. Basically, I need to have some text (bold and unbold) wrap within a `Stackpanel` or `Wrappanel` nicely. Here is a visual:

[image]

I need a combination of the two `TextBlocks` that you see. I've got the first bold `TextBlock` which contains "Title: " and then on the same line I need the next `TextBlock` which may or may not wrap. If it does wrap, I need the top line to stay on the top line and then wrap, as if it were all one `TextBlock`. Here's a made-in-Paint visual of what I need:

[image]

Here's my code that I've got so far:

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Text="Title: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="More text goes here " />
</toolkit:WrapPanel>

<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Text="Title: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="More text goes here and I want it to wrap lines and go underneath the title but I can't get it to to do that. :( " />
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Now, I'm **not** opposed to this being done in **one** `TextBlock` either (if possible). I know that with `TextBlock.Inlines` I can add a `Run` of bold text and then another of regular text. The problem with that is `Inlines` [cannot be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines) using MVVM (which I'm not using in this demonstration, but will be using in the final code).

So whatever the solution is, I need to be able to set the values of the `TextBlock`s from the code-behind so that I know it can be done with MVVM.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: So, you want to bind to a single source of text and some of that text might be bold?

Comment: Potentially, yes. I need the title to be bold and the rest not. If it were easier though, the titles can be in separate textblocks.

Comment: I would recommend the use of `Run` where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `RichTextBox` control with a different run for every font style.

```
<RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run FontWeight="Bold">Title:</Run>
        <Run>More text goes here and I want it to wrap lines and go underneath the title but I can't get it to to do that. :(</Run>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

You can bind the Text property of the `Run` elements to your data context, ex.:

```
    <RichTextBox>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run FontWeight="Bold"
                 Text="{Binding Header}"></Run>
            <Run Text="{Binding Text}"></Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. It occurred to me earlier that Silverlight's `RichTextBox` is an actual text box that users can type in, and for a second I assumed this wouldn't work. I did not know that the Windows Phone `RichTextBox` was more like the `TextBlock` rather than a `TextBox`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This would helpful for you:

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock>       
       <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Header}"></Run>     
        <Run Text="{Binding Text}"></Run>    
    </TextBlock>
</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Did you test this? AFAIK, `Run`s must be inside a `<TextBlock.Inlines>` (I assume you meant `TextBlock` and not `TextBox`) container, and as I mentioned in my post, `Inlines` of a `TextBlock` cannot be bound with MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Fix Width Property of both StackPanel. this may help you. Problem is if you don't set Width Property it consider as Auto width.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400">
   <TextBlock Text="Title: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="More text goes here " />
</StackPanel >

<StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400">
   <TextBlock Text="Title: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="More text goes here and I want it to wrap lines and go underneath the title but I can't get it to to do that. :( " />
</StackPanel >
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe I tried something like this, binding the `Width` of the `StackPanel` to the `ActualWidth` of it's parent. If I remember correctly, it *almost* worked but when the text would wrap, the text from the second `TextBlock` would not go directly underneath that of the first. I will try this again tonight though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using construction like this?

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Bold>
            <Bold.Inlines>
                <Run Text="Title: "/>
            </Bold.Inlines>
        </Bold>
        <Run Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

It works like a charm if text-block should be bound to just one block of text.