# TextBlock TextWrapping Wrap and NoWrap combined and Text through DynamicResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, word-wrap, dynamicresource

I have got multiple TextBlocks whose Text is inserted through DynamicResource. They are all set to TextWrapping="Wrap". But inside those Text-strings I have words which are not allowed to be split up. Those words must be kept as a whole word.

With hardcoded Text in Xaml it's quite easy solved via a TextBlock inside a Textblock:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
Example text with wrap and <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text=" example text without wrap"/
</TextBlock>
```

But this solution does not work when Text the is inserted through DynamicResource, because the text is not getting parsed.

How can I combine nowrap and wrap inside a DynamicResource Text without splitting it into multiple TextBlocks one after another?

PS: I have now created an **example to demonstrate the behavior** I would like (**green**) and the **failed attempts (red, orange, darkred)** of solving it:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="80" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="green">
                bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="Together(en)"/> bla5 bla6 longWordWhichShouldBreak
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="red">
                bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 Together(en) bla5 bla6 longWordWhichShouldBreak
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="orange">
                bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4&#160;Together(en)&#160;bla5 bla6 longWordWhichShouldBreak
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Foreground="DarkRed">
                bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4&#160;Together(en)&#160;bla5 bla6 longWordWhichShouldBreak
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Sounds like your so called "DynamicResource" is not suitable structured for usage in WPF. How about some preprocessing into a sequence of text chunks where each chunk has its display options?

Comment: Yes preprocessing into multiple sequence of text, in nowrap and wrap pieces is a solution. But it's relatively costly. I thought that there is a better solution of keeping just a single word together in wrap textblock.

Comment: Generally, you may have better luck with the `TextBlock.Inlines` property than the `TextBlock.Text` property. You can't expect the `Text` property to do anything else than just eating your text as... well text.

Comment: Thank your for this hint with Inlines! But Inlines is not bindable and can not be injected with a DynamicResource I think.

Comment: Uh, surprise... but the point is, when you write `<TextBlock Text="X"/>` you use `Text`, but when you write `<TextBlock>X</TextBlock>` the `TextBlock.Inlines` collection is used, __not__ the `Text` property. So don't hope to emulate your written XAML without using the inlines.

Answer (score 3):

Use [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) in your dynamic text. For example:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
        Example text with wrap and example text&#160;without&#160;wrap
</TextBlock>
```

You can replace space with this char in those parts that you need this behaviour:

```
  Replace(" ", System.Convert.ToChar(160))
```

Comment: Thank you. No-break space would be a good solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work:

[Screenshot of no-break space xaml and window](http://666kb.com/i/dh38s0g1zt1hss3k8.png)

Comment: This is how things work with ``TextWrapping="Wrap"``. Even if you use a long word, it will break it in order to wrap it in the available space. Use ``TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"`` and the result is similar to using ``TextBlock`` within ``TextBlock``,(i.e., the example in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using '`WrapWithOverflow`' instead of '`Wrap`'?
This will only break the line if a space appears.

You can then set the words that must appear together with dashes,e.g.-
'regular line and words-that-shouldn't-break'

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have also tried WrapWithOverflow. The problem with this setting is that the text is partly standing out and therefore not visible (cut off).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Run:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text={x:static SomeText} />
    <Run Text={x:static SomeNoWrapText}
         TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    <Run Text={x:static SomeMoreText} />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Using run has the same effect as using textblock inside textblock. It does work in XAML-Code directly but it does not work when inserted through dynamic ressource.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit much for a comment, but also not a complete answer.

Lets translate your example piece of XAML from all the implicit contents to a full qualified structure.

Your simplified XAML, using the implicit content properties and so on:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="green">
    bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="Together(en)"/> bla5 bla6 longWordWhichShouldBreak
</TextBlock>
```

Equivalent actual structure:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="green">
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 "/>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <InlineUIContainer.Child>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="Together(en)"/>
            </InlineUIContainer.Child>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run Text=" bla5 bla6 longWordWhichShouldBreak"/>
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

This should give you some idea about the complexity of what you have in your XAML. You can't archieve the same result by simply setting the `Text` property.

Currently I can't answer how to solve this issue, since `DynamicResource` is not enough information to start transforming into above structure.

You may want to have a look at this question: [Data binding the TextBlock.Inlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines)