# Is it possible to bind List of object to TextBlock like ListView in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I'm try convert my app framework to MVVM

and currently, I'm stuck at try to bind the `TextBlock`

This `TextBlock` on old project is update with code behind by adding new `Run` to the `TextBlock`

somewhat like this

On `MainPage.xaml`

```
<Page>
    <!--other items on page-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="textUI"/>
</Page>
```

On `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    void AddText(string text, bool mark)
    {
        if (mark)
        {
             textUI.Inlines.Add(new Run() 
                 {
                      Text = text,
                      Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Resources["SystemAccentColor"]) });
        }
        else
        {
             textUI.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = text });
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the question**

Instead, I try thinking other idea. And that idea was making `List` of class like this

```
public class Blocks
{
     public string text;
     public bool mark;
}
```

And put that on the list and bind it like on `ListView` but on the `TextBlock` instead

Like this

```
<TextBlock ItemSource={x:Bind ListOfBlocks}>
    <Run Text={x:Bind text,Mode=OneWay} Foreground={x:Bind mark, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, Mode=OneWay }
</TextBlock>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I'd do that with an ItemsControl and an appropriate DataTemplate and a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as the itemspanel.

Comment: Also you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines (the second answer about subclassing the TextBlock)