# WPF. Binding inside listbox itemtemplate to ObservableCollection source. Source PropertyChanged is ignored

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemtemplate

I'm trying to create a ListBox that displays formatted text. I want to be able to change formatting from code.

For displaying formatted text I chose TextBlock and intend to use the TextBlock.Inlines collection for formatting. TextBlock.Inlines is not bindable so I created new class **BindableTextBlock** derived from TextBlock. This class has one dependency property **InlineList** that I'm trying to bind to **InlinesColl** ObservableCollection in Model.

The problem is that changes in **InlinesColl** don't notify my **InlineList** about PropertyChanged event. Binding is functioned just once at **BindableTextBlock** object creation time and never after.

Any ideas why?

XAML:

```
                <ListBox  x:Name="PART_lb" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemColl}"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                    
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:BindableTextBlock InlineList="{Binding Path=InlinesColl}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    
                </ListBox>
```

BindableTextBlock class:

```
 public class BindableTextBlock : TextBlock
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Inline> InlineList
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Inline>)GetValue(InlineListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InlineListProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InlineListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InlineList", typeof(ObservableCollection<Inline>), typeof(BindableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindableTextBlock textBlock = (BindableTextBlock)sender;
            textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
            textBlock.Inlines.AddRange((ObservableCollection<Inline>)e.NewValue);
        }

      
    }
```

Model class

```
    public class TextBlockModel
    {

        ObservableCollection<Inline> _inlinesColl = new ObservableCollection<Inline>();
        public ObservableCollection<Inline> InlinesColl
        {
            get { return _inlinesColl; }
            set {_inlinesColl = value; }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel with collection for ListBox ItemSource

```
        ObservableCollection<TextBlockModel> _itemColl = new ObservableCollection<TextBlockModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<TextBlockModel> ItemColl
        {
            get { return _itemColl; }
            set { _itemColl = value; }
        }
```

Test project [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aosy83HLtFyekck9ICSIcby0CMtFLg?e=I2Udyq)

Answer (score 1):

In your case - you didn't handle case when item inside collection added\deleted
Need go deeply and subscirbe to CollectionChanged when new collection will be assigned.

```
 public class BindableTextBlock : TextBlock
    {
        static int Cntr = 0;
        public BindableTextBlock()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BindableTextBlock constructor " + Cntr);
            Cntr++;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Inline> InlineList
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Inline>)GetValue(InlineListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InlineListProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InlineListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InlineList", typeof(ObservableCollection<Inline>), typeof(BindableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindableTextBlock textBlock = (BindableTextBlock)sender;

            // subscribe to collection changed
            textBlock.UpdateInlineListSource((ObservableCollection < Inline > )e.OldValue, (ObservableCollection < Inline > )e.NewValue);

        }

        public void UpdateInlineListSource(ObservableCollection<Inline> oldCollection, ObservableCollection<Inline> newCollection)
        {
            if (oldCollection!=null)
            oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;

            if (newCollection != null)
            {
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
                OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
                OnCollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, newCollection));
            }
        }

        private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newItems = e.NewItems?.Cast<Inline>()?.ToList() ?? new List<Inline>();
            var oldItems = e.OldItems?.Cast<Inline>()?.ToList() ?? new List<Inline>();

            // changed source
            if (e.Action==NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
                this.Inlines.Clear();

            foreach (var itemForDelete in oldItems)
            {
                if (this.Inlines.Contains(itemForDelete))
                    this.Inlines.Remove(itemForDelete);
            }

            foreach (var itemsForAdd in newItems)
            {
                this.Inlines.Add(itemsForAdd);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Anton! Now it function as expected! I see where my mistake was.