# Data binding the TextBlock Runs in Avalonia

Tags: c#, data-binding, avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to do this

[image: Text with different colors]

from this view model

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<TextRun> RunList { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        RunList = new ObservableCollection<TextRun>(new List<TextRun>
            {
                new TextRun("Th", "Red"),
                new TextRun("is", "Green"),
                new TextRun(" i", "Maroon"),
                new TextRun("s ", "Blue"),
                new TextRun("a ", "Yellow"),
                new TextRun("te", "Black"),
                new TextRun("st", "Orange"),
                new TextRun("!!", "Violet"),
                new TextRun("!!", "Cyan")
            });
    }
}

public class TextRun
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public TextRun(string title, string color)
    {
        Text = title;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

exactly the same way this extract of the [accepted answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959856/data-binding-the-textblock-inlines) suggest:

> You may alternatively want to consider exposing an abstract model of
> text, font, etc. (i.e. a view model) and creating the actual Inline
> objects via a DataTemplate.

i.e. **no code, only axaml**. Sadly, the linked answer doesn't expand on this way of doing things and I need the details. I've spent the last two days trying out different combinations and I'm almost starting to hit my head against the wall. But in principle it should be easy. For instance, if the text were to be on different lines, this would be the axaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RunList}" >
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

but I need the text with different colors to be on the same line.

I know I must be using runs. This static axaml manages to do exactly that:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="Th" Foreground="Red"/><Run Text="is" Foreground="Green"/><Run Text=" a" Foreground="Blue"/><Run Text=" t" Foreground="Yellow"/><Run Text="es" Foreground="Black"/><Run Text="t!" Foreground="Orange"/><Run Text="!!" Foreground="Violet"/>
</TextBlock>
```

But I need it to be "Modelview binded" (Dynamic) as the extract suggest.

I just started playing with Avalonia the day before yesterday, so I'm fumbling in the dark here, please bear with me. So far it feels intuitive. This is the first speed bump I hit.

Included WPF tag because the WPF's xaml solution to this problem should be very similar to Avalonia's axaml. Sadly, I have no WPF experience either.

Update:

As [Danial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21044729/danial) suggested (I'm very very grateful for your suggestion!), I tried his variant:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="Th" Foreground="Red"/><Run Text="is" Foreground="Green"/><Run Text=" i" Foreground="Maroon"/><Run Text="s " Foreground="Blue"/><Run Text="a " Foreground="Yellow"/><Run Text="te" Foreground="Black"/><Run Text="st" Foreground="Orange"/><Run Text="!!" Foreground="Violet"/><Run Text="!!" Foreground="Cyan"/>
</TextBlock>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RunList}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

(Added the "static runs" variant for visual reference)

This is the result:

[image: Static runs vs Danial's variant]

Notice the extra gap at every run's end, and the misalignment at the right end of the image (the exclamations marks are not aligned because of the accumulated extra gaps). Its very close to what I'm looking for (visually), but not there yet.

Any other idea?

Comment: Why would you not create a class derived from TextBlock and add a bindable property, exactly as shown in that answer?

Comment: I want to use the least custom-code possible, and besides, it seems doable using only databinding/templates. Sorry for the lateness of this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind in a stackpanel with horizental orbitation.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RunList}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I will test it later. Sorry for the tardiness, right now I'm in the middle of a PC reinstall (haven't installed VS yet). One thing that worries me is the horizontal spacing between the "runs", I need it to be as in the shown example (no extra space).